# When using Bag.to_textfiles with dask, I get the error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'"

Tags: python, dask

Title says most of it
but the object in question is:

```
>>> import dask.bag as db
>>> b = db.from_sequence([{'name': 'Alice',   'balance': 100},
...                       {'name': 'Bob',     'balance': 200},
...                       {'name': 'Charlie', 'balance': 300}],
...                      npartitions=2)
```

but when I try

```
>>> b.to_textfiles('*.json')
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Traceback
---------
  File "/Users/jlatmann/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 267, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/Users/jlatmann/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 249, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/Users/jlatmann/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bag/core.py", line 1025, in write
    if not (firstline.endswith(os.linesep) or firstline.endswith('\n')):
```

dask version: 0.9.0

sys.version

> 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]

thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_textfiles` function assumes that the elements of the bag are strings.  I recommend mapping `str` on your bag first

```
b.map(str).to_textfiles('*.json')
```

Or better yet, given that your output files are json, dump your data to json format explicitly

```
b.map(json.dumps).to_textfiles('*.json')
```

Comment: <face palm/> but thank-you. and thanks for dask. On review of docs, and despite how obvious it is in retrospect, I would humbly suggest an amendment.

Comment: Can I interest you in submitting a quick pull request with the change?

Comment: definitely. (I just need to nail this thing down - which I haven't done yet: got another, very related, problem...)